# Elasticsearch error: [exists] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [field]

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to get my elasticsearh query to work, but I get this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: [exists] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [field]
```

The query is supposed to get all documents that have dates in either date.old or date.new between the two years(1500,1550), and also include documents that have undefined values for those fields.

This is my query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "date.old":{
                     "gte":1500,
                     "lte":1550
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "date.new":{
                     "gte":1500,
                     "lte":1550
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":{
                     "exists":{
                        "field":"date.new"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":{
                     "exists":{
                        "field":"date.old"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Do anyone see the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 7.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hitting the same search query as given in the question above gives no parsing error.**

Adding a working example with index mapping, index data, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "properties": {
          "old": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "new": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "new": 1501,
    "old": 10
  }
}

{
  "title": "elasticsearch"
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "65112793",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "date": {
        "new": 1501,
        "old": 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "65112793",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "elasticsearch"
    }
  }
]
```

**EDIT 1:**

Based on the comment below:

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date.old": {
              "gte": 1500,
              "lte": 1550
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date.new": {
              "gte": 1500,
              "lte": 1550
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "date.new"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "date.old"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I might have posted the question too fast. Thank you for your response. However, I am wondering if you know how to get the two last bool's as logical AND instead of OR ?

Comment: @kw123 please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue? And thank u for accepting the answer, can you please upvote the answer as well :)

Comment: Of course! It almost works, however, I don't get any data back with it. I want the first should parameter to be OR'ed with the must parameter, so that I will get the documents that either has a date between the range, or are missing both fields.. Do you know how to solve that? @ESCoder

Comment: @kw123 sorry I didn't get you. Can you please explain your use case with an example ?